# How to hide all files with a certain filename extension in Nemo?

Tags: files, file-manager, nemo

I've got a bunch of dxvk-cache files in a particular folder that really adds a lot of clutter. I tried making a `.hidden` file in the folder with `*.dxvk-cache` as a line to hide them from my file manager (Nemo), but that didn't work.

I saw another similar question, but that solution relied on a script that just prepended a dot before the file name. I'm not looking to rename the files `.whatever.dxvk-cache` because that will just cause the original file to be regenerated. Is there a convenient way to solve this?

Comment: are you looking for `--hide`feature of ls ? you mention "file mnager" can you name it ?

Comment: The one and only common way to "hide" files on unix systems is indeeed to start their name with a dot. There may be other non-common ways, but we need to know the file system and the file browser.

Comment: I usually use Nemo, but I'm looking for whatever the convention might be between most Linux GUI file managers. Usually, the way to hide hidden files without prepending them with a dot would be to add them to a .hidden file inside the same folder, but the asterisk doesn't act like a catch-all how it normally does.